# Reestablish connection to parent repo

Tags: git, github

I made a fork of a private repository in my organization. I was able to make PRs to the parent repo fine

Recently our org admin changed the private repo to a public one and now the forked connection is not there anymore. Now I can't make any more PRs and the original parent repo does not have any more forks assoicated with it.

is there a way to reestablish connection to the parent repo?

Edit: This is all on the github website

Answer (score 0):

According to GitHub...

> If a private repository is made public, each of its private forks is
>   turned into a standalone private repository and becomes the parent of
>   its own new repository network.

There is no mention of a way to reestablish a connection from an existing standalone private repository to the converted public repository on GitHub directly.  You could however, change it locally if you have cloned the forked repo by running `git remote set-url upstream git://yourorg.com/yourRepo.git`

So it looks like your best option is to just fork the converted public repo.

Comment: This problem is for the repo on github

Comment: Did you try and re-fork the repo after it was converted to public?

Comment: Yeah that worked, but I was wondering if there was a way to reestablish the connection with the fork I already had